# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() when using AsyncTask

Tags: android

I have the following code in my app that should update the app. I host the apk on a private server and when i put a new version i want this code to run and update the app.

I know the Play Store does this and we use that mechanism for most of our customers. There are a few customers who refuse to have background data switched on due to data usage. These customer can't use the Play Store, so i want a graceful update method from our private server.

I have read a posts on SO and the general feeling is that i'm calling something that should be called on the UI thread. If i'm making a web call, it must be on a BG thread.

Any ideas why i'm getting this error message?

Thanks in advance

Matt

```
 String url = "http://cfweb.yourofficeanywhere.co.uk/entryactivityv33.apk";

    String[] updateParam = new String[] {url};
    AsyncUpdateApp asua = new AsyncUpdateApp();
    asua.execute(updateParam);
```

.

```
private class AsyncUpdateApp extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String result = updateApp(params[0]);

            return result;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){

              Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
              intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
              intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              startActivity(intent);

            }else{

                Log.e(TAG, "result odf updateApp = ERROR");

            }
        }




    }


    public String updateApp(String apkurl){
        try {
              URL url = new URL(apkurl);
              HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              c.setRequestMethod("GET");
              c.setDoOutput(true);
              c.connect();

              String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
              File file = new File(PATH);
              file.mkdirs();
              File outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk");
              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

              InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

              byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              int len1 = 0;
              while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                  fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
              }
              fos.close();
              is.close();//till here, it works fine - .apk is download to my sdcard in download file

              return "OK";



          } catch (IOException e) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              return "ERROR";
          }
    }  //end of updateApp
```

.

```
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606): Process: com.carefreegroup.rr3, PID: 606
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:327)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcscannerActivity.updateApp(NfcscannerActivity.java:6382)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcscannerActivity$AsyncUpdateApp.doInBackground(NfcscannerActivity.java:6320)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at com.carefreegroup.rr3.NfcscannerActivity$AsyncUpdateApp.doInBackground(NfcscannerActivity.java:1)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-10 14:31:04.975: E/AndroidRuntime(606):  ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of code throws an IOException:

```
try {
              URL url = new URL(apkurl);
              HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              c.setRequestMethod("GET");
              c.setDoOutput(true);
              c.connect();

              String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
              File file = new File(PATH);
              file.mkdirs();
              File outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk");
              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

              InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

              byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              int len1 = 0;
              while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                  fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
              }
              fos.close();
              is.close();//till here, it works fine - .apk is download to my sdcard in download file

              return "OK";



          }
```

And in catch block you can not run any UI operation in doInBackground you must remove this line from catch:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to display **`Toast`** in **`Background Thread`**. Thats the problem. You can replace toast line with log.

```
       // Some code...
      } catch (IOException e) {
          //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Log.e("Error","Exception thrown");
          return "ERROR";
      }
```